# Question about the String.replaceAll() and String.replaceFirst() method

Tags: java, string, replace

I need to do a simple string replace operation on a segment of string. I ran into the following issue and hope to get some advice.

1. In the original string I got, I can replace the string such as `<div class="more">` to something else.
2. BUT, in the same original string, if I want to replace a much long string such as the following, it won’t work.  Nothing gets replaced after the call.

`<div class="more"><a href="http://SERVER_name/profiles/atom/mv/theboard/entries/related.do?email=xyz.com&amp;ps=20&amp;since=1273518953218&amp;sinceEntryId=abc-def-123-456">More...</a></div>`

I tried these two methods:

```
originalString.replaceFirst(moreTag, newContent);
originalString.replaceAll(moreTag, newContent);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't access your "More" link.

Comment: I can't seem to browse to that link of yours

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a link, I think -- it was a code sample describing a link.  I've added code formatting.

Comment: Better give us the explicit code: what are you putting in the "originalString" and "moreTag" variables when you do `originalString.replaceAll(moreTag, newContent)`, and how are you checking for success?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get hold of the result of the replacement and use it further:

```
String newString = originalString.replaceFirst(moreTag, newContent);
System.out.println(newString);
```

Explanation: strings in Java are **immutable**. The behavioral methods of `java.lang.String` won't change the internal value. They instead will *return* the modified result.

If that still doesn't return the desired result, then the `moreTag` simply didn't match anything. The methods you mentioned expects a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info). You can find in the [`Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) javadoc how to compose a valid regex pattern.

Comment: hello,all
Thanks for the quick responses. 
I defined the moreTag like this where I considered the escape character, and replaceAll() works in this case.
String moreTag = new String("<div class=\"more\">");

However, when I construct the longer string such as the one showed  in my original question, I did not do anything about the double quotes or http://

I got the string like this:
String removedMoreTag=finalContent.substring(moreStartIndex, moreSecondIndex+6);

Is this the problem?  Should I do something about the double quotes in this removedMoreTag before making the replaceAll() call?

Comment: [You shouldn't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You need to parse HTML with a HTML parser. I recommend [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for this.

Comment: Hello, I am back again. I was able to find the solution using Java 1.5 API (String myFinalContent = finalContent.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(string1), Matcher.quoteReplacement(string2));).  Now, I just found out that in the codestream I am building, I can only use Java 1.4 API.  Could somebody advice me how I can easily convert a string to REGULAR EXPRESSION?  I did lots of research last night but could not find an answer.  Really appreciated....

Comment: @Java Doe: You just need to **manually** quote the pattern and the replacement. Do `System.out.println()` of them in Java 1.5 to learn how they should actually look like and use that instead. Or look/copy the source of those Java 1.5 methods.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your code ?

Are you aware that your *moreTag* string (the first argument to replaceFirst/replaceAll) is assumed to be a regular expression ?

If you dont want regular expressions here, you can use the plain [replace](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace) method.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, do you save the result of replace operation?

Test you regular expression if it really matches what do you think, you'll find some tools for that online. Especially take care of proper escaping of special characters.

Also, if you do not need regular expressions, consider using StringTokenizer and StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of [`replaceAll`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and [`replaceFirst`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) usage:

```
    String s = "Hi there! John here!";

    s = s.replaceAll("ere", "arrr");
    System.out.println(s);
    // prints "Hi tharrr! John harrr!"

    s = s.replaceFirst("!", "?");
    System.out.println(s);
    // prints "Hi tharrr? John harrr!"
```

As others have mentioned, both are actually regex-based:

```
    System.out.println("Hello???".replaceAll("?", "!"));
    // throws PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?'
```

The problem here is that `?` is a regex metacharacter, and to treat it as a literal question mark, you have to escape it:

```
    System.out.println("Hello???".replaceAll("\\?", "!"));
    // prints "Hello!!!"
```

Sometimes the string the pattern is an unknown, in which case you can use [`Pattern.quote`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
    String unknown = "?";
    System.out.println(
        "Hello???".replaceAll(Pattern.quote(unknown), "!")
    ); // prints "Hello!!!"
```

To complicate matters slightly, the replacement string is actually also regex-based.

```
    System.out.println(
        "USD 10".replaceAll("USD", "dollar$")
    );
    // throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index out of range: 7
```

To quote a replacement string, you use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29):

```
    System.out.println(
        "USD 10".replaceAll("USD", Matcher.quoteReplacement("dollar$"))
    ); // prints "dollar$ 10"
```

---

> ***But what if I just want to do a simple no-regex replacement?***

Then, to use `replaceFirst`, you have to quote both the pattern and the replacement strings:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;


String replaceFrom = ...;
String replaceTo = ...;

String before = ...;

String after = before.replaceFirst(
   Pattern.quote(replaceFrom), Matcher.quoteReplacement(replaceTo)
);
```

And if you need a `replaceAll`, then you just use the usual non-regex `replace` method instead:

```
String after = before.replace(replaceFrom, replaceTo);
```